# How to calculate $\oint_{C_r}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi w}(w-N)dw$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to calculate $m = \oint_{C_r}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi w}(w-N)dw$, where $N$ is an fixed integer and $C_r$ is a circle centered at $N$ such that the radius $0 < r < 1$.

I am trying to use the routine method, let $w=re^{it}$ and we know that $\sin^2(\pi z)=\frac{1-e^{2\pi i z}}{2}$, then $\oint_{C_r}\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi w}(w-N)dw= i\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2}{1-e^{2\pi i r e^{it}}}r^2 e^{2it}dt$, how should I proceed?

Comment: Please do change your question's title for something that makes sense...

Comment: I'd say you are supposed to use the residue theorem, or equivalently, substract to $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi z}$ the rational function $\displaystyle\sum_{n = -\lfloor r \rfloor}^{\lfloor r \rfloor} \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ and say the difference is holomorphic

Comment: sorry I have edited the question.

Comment: anything unclear with what I wrote ? do you know the Cauchy integral theorem ? and how to compute $\int_{C_r} \frac{w}{(w-n)^2}dw$ ?

Comment: How to calculate the $Res(\frac{\pi^2}{sin^2\pi w}(w-N);N)$? @user1952009

Comment: What is the definition of a residue ? What are the 1st few terms of the Laurent series of your function at $w = N$ ?

Comment: Isn't the residue of $g(w)(w-N)$ just be the integral that I want to calculate if I am using the Laurent series to get its residue.

Comment: The only residue I can see your function has in $\;C_r\;$ and its interior is zero...Why would you care about $\;N\;$ ??

Comment: If I know the order of pole of $f(w)$ at $N$, then I would be able to find its residue. Now consider $h(w)= \frac{sin^2\pi w}{\pi^2}$, $h(N) = 0$, $h'(N) = 0$, and $h^{(2)}(N) \neq 0$, so it has a zero of order $2$, then $f(w)$ would have a pole of order 2. Then I get $a_{-2} = (f(w)(w-N))''$ evaluated at $N$

Comment: "The order of N" ? Isn´t  N  an integer? And if the circle has radius $\;<1\;$ then no integer **but zero** is a pole of the function within the integration domain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function's only pole within the domain enclosed by the curve $\;C_r:\;|z|=r<1\;$  is a double one at $\;w=0\;$. Let's evaluate the residue there:

$$\frac{(w-N)}{\sin^2\pi w}=\frac{w-N}{\left(\pi w-\frac{\pi^3w^3}6+\mathcal O(w^5)\right)^2}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac{w-N}{\pi^2w^2-\frac{\pi^4w^4}3+\mathcal O(w^6)}=\frac{w-N}{\pi^2w^2\left(1-\frac{\pi^2 w^2}3+\mathcal O(w^4)\right)}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac1{\pi^2}\left(\frac1w-\frac N{w^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{\pi^2 w^2}3+\frac{\pi^4w^4}9+\ldots\right)=\ldots\frac1{\pi^2w}+\ldots$$

and thus the residue at zero of the whole function is $\;1\;$